# Lower bound of infinite sum of shifts

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, periodic-functions, almost-periodic-function

This is an extension of https://mathoverflow.net/posts/452526.

So, it appears that $\sin(xt)$ serves as a better lower bound instead of a linear equation, in fact the series appears to uniformly approach $\sin(xt)$ as $x\to 0$, yielding a ratio of $1$ in their limit. I then went ahead and flipped over the function so that is would be between 0 and 1 (assuming the series is positive), and I then multiplied $t$ by $x$ so as to map the periodicity between $(0,1)$. I then graphed through different values of $x$ to see what $t$ looks like. The below animation is

$$ g(t,x):=\frac{f(x/2,x)*\sin(\pi t)}{f(xt,x)}$$

where the series uses the functions $f_2(t)=\tanh(t)e^{-\cosh(t)}$ and $f_5(t)=\tanh(t/2)e^{-\cosh(t)}$. We see that $f_2$ appears to be strictly decreasing as $x$ increases. Likewise, we see that $f_5$ appears to oscillate around $1$ at the start, in particular since the series for $f_5$ appears to be negative for some values of $x$, we see here the ratio is $>1$ for those same values of $x$. How would we prove that for $t>0$ and $f(t)=\tanh(t)e^{-\cosh(t)}$, we have

$$\frac{d}{dx} g(t,x) = \frac{d}{dx}\frac{f(x/2,x)*\sin(\pi t)}{f(xt,x)}\le 0 $$

for any $x$? How do we prove $\lim g(t,x)=1$ when $x\to 0$ and $\lim g(t,x)=0$ ($t\not= 1/2$) when $x\to\infty$? Working with this series seems particularly difficult, even though we can see what it is doing.

[image]